# Regex to replace string with another string in MS Word?

Tags: regex, ms-word

Can anyone help me with a regex to turn:

```
filename_author
```

to

```
author_filename
```

I am using MS Word 2003 and am trying to do this with Word's Find-and-Replace.  I've tried the `use wildcards` feature but haven't had any luck.

Am I only going to be able to do it programmatically?

Comment: Actually I need to use this on an editor that supports regex. C++/C# should be fine I assume.

Comment: -1: which language?  Which editor?

Comment: So the text you want to replace is in a MS Word document?

Comment: Yep. It's in the whole document.

Comment: When I try, word tells me that it cannot find the string.

Comment: Please see my most recent edit to my original answer.

Comment: @Joan, I hope my edits still maintain the spirit of your question while clarifying your intent a little.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the regex:

> `([^_]*)_(.*)`

And here is a C# example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        String test = "filename_author";
        String result = Regex.Replace(test, @"([^_]*)_(.*)", "$2_$1");
    }
}
```

Here is a Python example:

```
from re import sub

test = "filename_author";
result = sub('([^_]*)_(.*)', r'\2_\1', test)
```

---

**Edit:** In order to do this in Microsoft Word using wildcards use this as a search string:

> `(<*>)_(<*>)`

and replace with this:

> `\2_\1`

Also, please see [Add power to Word searches with regular expressions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA010873051033.aspx) for an explanation of the syntax I have used above:

> - The asterisk (*) returns all the text in the word.
> - The less than and greater than symbols (< >) mark the start and end
>     of each word, respectively. They
>     ensure that the search returns a
>     single word.
> - The parentheses and the space between them divide the words into
>     distinct groups: (first word) (second
>     word). The parentheses also indicate
>     the order in which you want search to
>     evaluate each expression.

Comment: I might have to do this in code I guess. Do you know what I would need, if I have to replace the second part with a fixed text like "myname_filename"?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
s/^([a-zA-Z]+)_([a-zA-Z]+)$/\2_\1/
```

Depending on the context, that might be a little greedy.

Answer (score 2):

Search pattern:

```
([^_]+)_(.+)
```

Replacement pattern:

```
$2_$1
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET you could use `([^_]+)_([^_]+)` as the regex and then `$2_$1` as the substitution pattern, for this very specific type of case. If you need more than 2 parts it gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: As others have noted, (.*) would be better for the second part of the regex than ([^_]+).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in MS Word, you might try a non-programming approach. Highlight all of the text, select Table -> Convert -> Text to Table. Set the number of columns at 2. Choose Separate Text At, select the Other radio, and enter an _. That will give you a table. Switch the two columns. Then convert the table back to text using the _ again.

Or you could copy the whole thing to Excel, construct a formula to split and rejoin the text and then copy and paste that back to Word. Either would work.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you could also do something like this.

```
string[] parts = "filename_author".Split('_');
return parts[1] + "_" + parts[0];
```

You asked about regex of course, but this might be a good alternative.